# custom adapter with ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>

Tags: android, hashmap, adapter

Its a really complicated question, but I hope someone can help me.

I want to make a custom adapter that can handle

Array List mentioned in the title

Currently I am doing this, but its not even going into getView(...) method.

```
public class EventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> eventList;

private Context context;
private int resource;

   private static final String TAG_TITLE = "e_title";


public EventsAdapter(Context context, int resId,ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> eventList)
{

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resId;
    this.eventList = eventList;
    Log.v("chk", "1");

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View event = convertView;

    TextView title, desc, date, time, venue;

    HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = eventList.get(position);



    List<String> items = hm.get(TAG_TITLE);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Ubahn.ttf"); 

    if( event == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        event = inflater.inflate( resource , parent, true  );
        event.setTag(items.get(position));
    }

    title = (TextView) event.findViewById( R.id.etitle);
    desc = (TextView) event.findViewById( R.id.edesc );
    date = (TextView)event.findViewById(R.id.edate);
    time = (TextView)event.findViewById(R.id.etiming);
    venue = (TextView)event.findViewById(R.id.elocation);

    title.setTypeface(font);



    System.out.print(items.get(0).toString());

    title.setText(items.get(0).toString());
    desc.setText(items.get(1).toString());
    date.setText(items.get(2).toString());
    time.setText(items.get(3).toString());
    venue.setText(items.get(4).toString());

    return event;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 5;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return eventList.get(position).get(position).get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I am filling the data in the Array List

```
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    String venue = c.getString(TAG_VENUE);

                    // creating new HashMap

                    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                    List<String> el = new ArrayList<String>();
                    el.add(title);
                    el.add(description);
                    el.add(date);
                    el.add(time);
                    el.add(venue);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, el);
                   // map.put(TAG_DESC, description);
                    //muap.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    eventList.add(map);
                }
```

and then here I am setting the adapter

```
EventsAdapter adapter = new EventsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.events_list_item, eventList);



                lv.setAdapter( adapter);
```

Comment: Posted all the things except your problem?what problem you are facing ??

Comment: I just can't populate my list with data.
in this format: 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>

Comment: are you getting the data from arraylist and from hashmap

Comment: No, I am filling a list<String> with strings five times
then putting those Lists in hash map with key
then putting those hash maps in ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>

Comment: so basically I am getting data from just one ArrayList.
which is custom array list .
ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>

Comment: is this **System.out.print(items.get(0).toString());** printing the values while executing..

Comment: No . I tried to check whether the crawler is going in getView() method or not. but it isn't.

Comment: Also the amazing thing is app is not crashing. just there is empty view.

Comment: @Sharjeel Have you tried debugging your code? Are you sure its not going in `getView` method ? Show the code of how you are calling your adapter class.

Comment: @Sharjeel so post the code where your setting the Adapter in Activity

Comment: EventsAdapter adapter = new EventsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.events_list_item, eventList);
                    

                    
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be useful to consider *when* you are filling that list.

a good design pattern is to create the data as an empty hashmap, establish the adapter with that map, declare the listview( or whatever ) and then assign the adapter with the empty data set. later, fill the hashmap, and then adapter.notifydatasetchanged

I declare these feilds:

```
    //array of places filtered by keyword
List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>( );
    //spinner of places filtered by keyword
Spinner placesSpinner;
//adapter for spinner
private PlacesSpinnerAdapter placesSpinnerAdapter;
```

in onCreate:

```
//this is for a spinner, but same difference
placesSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById( R.id.placesSpinner );
placesSpinnerAdapter = new PlacesSpinnerAdapter( this, 
                           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, places );
placesSpinner.setAdapter( placesSpinnerAdapter );
```

and somewhere in the onPostExecute method of an AsyncTask you have no interest in

```
places.clear( );
places.addAll( result.results );
placesSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged( );
placesSpinner.performClick( );
```

and lastly, here's a difference I see: adapters do Lists, I've never had a good time passing them hashmaps... do a map.keySet() or map.values(); as you hand the data over to the adapter; I know for certain the very standard pattern I just described does not work if the data set is hashmaps

gl hf

Comment: yes I know the pattern is not too attractive, but logically I am doing everything right.

Comment: Ah. and also you most def need to call super(params) in that constructor in your adapter

Comment: Hrm, Looking at that futher, I don't know why you are using the HashMap like that; from what I can see, you are making a new HashMap for every element in the product list, and adding that single-row map to a list; why not just keep adding to the hashmap on each iteration, then passing hashMap.values() to the adapter? I think you should rethink that, but I'll bet Piyush's answer will get you some result

Comment: Yeah, I think that unless you are dealing with TAG_TITLE outside the adapter, just include it with the other data, forgo the hashmap altogether, and make it a ArrayList<<ArrayList<String>>>

Comment: Consider how many times getView is called, and how much work you are doing in there!

Comment: Yes I just realized that, Now I will just store data in hash map and pass that simply. 
Awesome thank you.

Comment: awesome, glad to help! gg hf

Comment: ...please remember to check off the answer if you care to... the point system here is addictive!

Comment: Sure, Sorry I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

return list size from `getCount` method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}
```

As the array list inside the adapter does not have 5 items(it has only one item) so try return the size of the list

Comment: No, it didn't solve the prob, but Now I am changing the logic all together. not saving the data in list anymore

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code for custom adapter java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList, int resource, String[] from ,int[] to) {
        super(context, arrayList, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) 
          view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is WelcomeActivity

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = "Define your list here"

        String[] from = new String[]{"name","phone"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.phone};
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,userList,R.layout.user_list_f,from,to);
        lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

it has been working for me perfectly